# Refresh a Gridview with dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic-data

I have a gridview with dynamic data fields. The gridview is on a form in a master detail relationship (There is a grid view and form view). I click add a new record, the form view appears, I fill it out, I click save. This all works. After saving, I want to refresh the grid view. If I load the gridview, I get:

'Could not determine a MetaTable'

Normally, this is solved by enabling dynamic data at the Page_Init event, but on a refresh of the grid view, this event does not seem to be firing. How can I 're-enable' dynamic data for this grid view?

Did I mention this is all on a wizard step?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, the problem was that the gridview was part of a user control. I needed to enable dynamic data on the actual page, not the user control.